# How can i call javascript function from a href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have two javascript functions madeAjaxCall() and getBookCall(bookId) to obtain book list and chapter list respectively.

I'm trying to call getBookCall(bookId) from within the function madeAjaxCall().

```
function madeAjaxCall(){
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:8080/restApp/book/list",
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(data){
            delete_table();
            if(data){
                var len = data.length;
                var txt = "";
                txt += "<tr><th>"+"bookId"+"</th><th>"+"bookName"+"</th><th>"+"Chapter Details"+"</th></tr>";   
                if(len > 0){
                    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                        if(data[i].bookId != null && data[i].bookName != null){                                        
                            /* txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].bookId+"</td><td>"+data[i].bookName+"</td><td><a href="+ "http://localhost:8080/restApp/chapter/list/"+ data[i].bookId +">"+"Chapter details"+"</a></td></tr>";       */           
                             txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].bookId+"</td><td>"+data[i].bookName+"</td><td><a href="+ "#"+" "+ "onclick=" +  +"getBookCall("+ data[i].bookId + ")"+";return false;" +">"+"Chapter details"+"</a></td></tr>";                  

                        }
                    }
                    if(txt != ""){
                        $("#table1").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

And the other function

```
function getBookCall(bookId){
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:8080/restApp/chapter/list/"+bookId,
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(data){
            delete_table2();
            if(data){
                var len = data.length;
                var txt = "";
                txt += "<tr><th>"+"chapterId"+"</th><th>"+"chapterName"+"</th></tr>";
                if(len > 0){
                    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                        if(data[i].chapterId != null && data[i].chapterName != null){
                            txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].chapterId+"</td><td>"+data[i].chapterName+"</td></tr>";                   
                        }
                    }
                    if(txt != ""){
                        $("#table2").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

I am obtaining list of books as JSON from the function **madeAjaxCall()** and appending the list in a table. I want to call the function **getBookCall(bookId)** from within the function madeAjaxCall() with the help of a href. But i am unable to call the function **getBookCall(bookId)** using a href, from within the function madeAjaxCall().

This is the line from the function madeAjaxCall from where the function getBookCall(bookId) could not be called.

```
txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].bookId+"</td><td>"+data[i].bookName+"</td><td><a href="+ "#"+" "+ "onclick=" +  +"getBookCall("+ data[i].bookId + ")"+";return false;" +">"+"Chapter details"+"</a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: `"onclick=" +  +"getBookCall("+` you can see there are two `+` after `onclick=`.

Comment: Thank you jai. Silly mistake from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here In example I have use custom `data-*` attribute to store `bookid`, which can be fetched using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), create your anchor like:

```
txt += '<a class="myBookLink" href="#" data-bookid="' + data[i].bookId + '">Chapter details</a>";
```

Then use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach to bind the click event handler of anchor.

```
$(document).on('click', function(){
    getBookCall($(this).data('bookid'))
    return false;
})
```

Important: In place of `document` you should always use closest static container.

**For Immediate solution use quotes properly.**

```
txt += "<tr><td>" 
    + data[i].bookId 
    + "</td><td>" 
    + data[i].bookName
    +'</td><td><a href="#" onclick="getBookCall('+ data[i].bookId + ');return false;">Chapter details</a></td></tr>';
```

instead of

```
txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].bookId+"</td><td>"+data[i].bookName+"</td><td><a href="+ "#"+" "+ "onclick=" +  +"getBookCall("+ data[i].bookId + ")"+";return false;" +">"+"Chapter details"+"</a></td></tr>";
```